# Map 2 fields from the same entity with another entity

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony2 forum application where, among others, I have 2 entities, namely "User" and "Conversation". A conversation is always between only 2 persons, and I need to know the user who started it and the user to whom it is addressed. This are called "userFrom" and "userTo". I want to map "userFrom" with "id" column from "User" and "userTo" with the same column from "User".

I made this:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Forum\CoreBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends Timestampable implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Conversation", mappedBy="fromUser")
     */
    private $conversationsFromUser;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Conversation", mappedBy="toUser")
     */
    private $conversationsToUser;
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Conversation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="conversation")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Forum\CoreBundle\Repository\ConversationRepository")
 */
class Conversation extends Timestampable
{
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="$conversationsFromUser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_from_user", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $fromUser;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="$conversationsToUser")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_to_user", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $toUser;
}
```

but Symfony2 complains saying "the mappings are inconsistent with each other".
I want that when I request:

- $user->getConversationsFromUser() to get a list of all the conversations started by that user
- $user->getConversationsToUser() to get a list of all the conversations to that user
- $conversation->getFromUser() to get the user who started that conversation
- $conversation->getToUser() to get the user to whom that conversation is sent

Is it possible to map what I want with Doctrine2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inversedBy="$conversationsFromUser"  => inversedBy="conversationsFromUser"

" $ " !!!

Comment: Damn, I don't think I would have seen that. Pretty sure this is the correct answer, unfortunately I can't test until tonight. Let you know how it goes.